# MediaPlayer is not preparing while playing from a url: MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an app which plays a song present on one android phone onto another using HTTP connection url. This is my code to initialize and start MediaPlayer :-

```
        Log.d(TAG, "Rohit insidePlaysong of client");
        mp.reset();
        Log.d(TAG, "Rohit Music player is reset");
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        Log.d(TAG, "Rohit Music player : data source set");

        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        Log.d(TAG, "Rohit Music player audio stream type set");

        //mp.prepare();
        //Rohit changing the method of preparing
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(TAG, "Rohit inside onPrepared, Now starting Music Player");
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        mp.prepareAsync();
        //mp.prepare();
        //Log.d(TAG, "Rohit Music player prepared");
        // TODO: make sure we have buffered REALLY
        // buffered the music, currently this is a big
        // HACK and takes a lot of time. We can do
        // better!
        /*mp.start();
        mp.pause();
        mp.start();
        mp.pause();
        mp.start();
        mp.pause();
        mp.start();
        mp.pause();
        mp.start();
        mp.pause();*/

        Log.d(TAG, "Rohit Music player started");

        musicTimer = mActivity.retrieveTimer();

        Log.d(TAG, "Rohit retrieved timer");

        // let the music timer determine when to play the future playback
        musicTimer.playFutureMusic(mp, startTime, startPos);

        Log.d(TAG, "Rohit future music set to timer");

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        // btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();
        // parsing songTitle

        Log.d(TAG, "Rohit updated song progress");
```

And these are the corresponding logs printed (filtered with "Rohit"):-

```
12-19 19:25:42.827   463   463 D Speaker Music Player: Rohit insidePlaysong of client
12-19 19:25:42.827   463   463 D Speaker Music Player: Rohit Music player is reset
12-19 19:25:42.847   463   463 D Speaker Music Player: Rohit Music player : data source set
12-19 19:25:42.847   463   463 D Speaker Music Player: Rohit Music player audio stream type set
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 D Speaker Music Player: Rohit Music player started
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 D Speaker Music Player: Rohit retrieved timer
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 D Speaker Music Player: Rohit future music set to timer
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 D Speaker Music Player: Rohit updated song progress
```

As you can see, "Rohit inside onPrepared, Now starting Music Player" is never prepared.

Although from url I can see that MediaPlayer is able to fetch songName properly, but I am getting the following error in my logs while using mp.getDuration() in my code:-

```
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 V MediaPlayer: getDuration_l<br>
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 E MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 V MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
12-19 19:25:42.857  3237  1397 V GenericSource: [Flag] set 0x8 -> mFlags = 0x8
12-19 19:25:42.857  3237  1398 V GenericSource: onPrepareAsync<br>
12-19 19:25:42.857  6089  6096 I art     : Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 E MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)<br>
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 V MediaPlayer: callback application
12-19 19:25:42.857  3438  3502 V BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{62bf8b6 u0 com.samsung.android.providers.context.log.action.USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{98bbb0 6103:com.samsung.android.providers.context/u0a8}
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 V MediaPlayer: back from callback
12-19 19:25:42.857   463   463 V MediaPlayer-JNI: getDuration: 0 (msec)
```

Can anyone please help me know, what are the possible reasons for this unability of MediaPlayer to prepare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are triyng to get duration without waiting for `MediaPlayer` to prepare. You don't have to use `MediaPlayer` until it prepared. So code below `prepareAsync` must be invoked in `prepareListener` callback:

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(url);
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        //any further actions on mediaPlayer here
    }
});
mp.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: I understand that I should do it there....But the problem is : my MediaPlayer never got prepared....I tried commenting all the code after mp.prepareAsync() statement also and waited for around a minute. But still the logs inside onPrepared() never got called.

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission in your manifest? Is URL correct? Do you have internet connection?

Comment: Yes INTERNET permission is there:-<br>

Comment: Yes INTERNET permission is there:-<br>
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:required="true" /><br>
Url is also correct as the same url is playing on one other device perfectly:
http://192.168.49.1:9002/The Departed.mp3.mp3<br>

Yes, internet connection is there.